# battery voltage supply too high for electronics

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, buck

I am driving brushless DC motors with an STM32 blue pill. My application includes said STM32 blue pill, L6234 motor drivers, 2 MPU5060 gyros and 2 AS5048a encoders.

I am using a 14.8V battery to feed the drivers. STM32, the gyros, and the encoders need to be fed with 5V.

My question is: what is my best (and perhaps easiest) option to feed the STM32 and the sensors?

So I was thinking about a buck (DC/DC) converter, but I am not sure how it is usually done. The STM32 and the sensors are low power, the motor drivers are high power.

[image]

Or is it possible to do such a thing with voltage regulators that can be found in Arduino Uno without them shutting down?

Comment: A buck converter is indeed the best way to do this.

Comment: How you ground everything is also of extreme importance.

Comment: The ADC sections need low ripple so LDO’s are preferred for final stage of conversion

Comment: MPU5060 max supply voltage is 3.46V. So I presume you are using gyro **modules** with on board regulators, right? What is the application?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yes, i am using GY-521 breakout boards. My application is gimbal.

Answer (score 0):

Convert 14.8V to 5V with using DC/DC switch mode converter module firstly.
[image]

Than convert 5V to 3.3VCC voltage with simple linear converter circuit that have enough tank capacitors.

[image: Example DC/DC switch mode converter]